# Adjust resolution of JAVA application Project (Chromis POS) on high DPI computers

Tags: java, swing, resolution

I am trying to edit some layouts of Chromis POS, JAVA based Point of Sales application but when I run the project on my computer with high DPI resolution the program fonts are too small in size difficulting reading as attached image.
The problem is that with the JAVA project within NetBeans I am unable to change the display of the program but if I install the .EXE program on my computer I can solve this by change some display properties going to program shortcut and program compatibility and try many options but within NetBeans I am unable.

Question: How to adjust the resolution of this program within NetBeans?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, help! I need this fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by installing Apache Netbeans 9.0 and using JAVA SE 11(JDK) in my project.
Done!